# Copying specific columns from text file to a new text file with python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm quite new to Python language.

I have a text file with multiple columns space delimited which looks like:

```
year month lat lon chl_a TSM NO2
1999 3.0 9.02 38.87 4.32 NaN NaN
1999 4.0 9.02 38.87 2.65 17.4 NaN
```

I would like to select some of the columns preferably by calling the column name (which are the names on the first raw) and copy the selected columns into a new text file. 
Is there a simple way to do it? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with `Pandas`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\s')

interested_cols = ['year', 'month','lat','lon']

df[interested_cols].to_csv('out.txt', sep=' ')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have tried it but I got the following error: ParserError: Expected 111 fields in line 6, saw 112. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: Can you add `quotechar='"'` or your corresponding quote character?

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not understanding. what is the quote character referring to? In my input file I don't have any quote character

Comment: `due to  quotes being ignored` what quote?

Comment: the error says: 'Error could POSSIBLY be due to quotes'. The fact is that there are no quotes in the text file

Comment: I see. You need to look at line 6, there are 111 spaces while other lines have only 110. Another option is try `sep='\s+'`.